# TSQL - Need to query a database column which is populated by XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

TSQL - Need to query a database column which is populated by XML.

The Database has an iUserID column with an Application ID and VCKey

TxtValue is the Column name and the contained Data is similar to this

```
<BasePreferencesDataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BasePreferencesDataSet.xsd">
<ViewModesTable>
<iViewID>1</iViewID>
</ViewModesTable>
<ViewMode_PreferenceData>
<iViewID>1</iViewID>
<iDataID>0</iDataID>
<strValue>False</strValue>
</ViewMode_PreferenceData>
<ViewMode_PreferenceData>
<iViewID>1</iViewID>
<iDataID>5</iDataID>
<strValue>True</strValue>
</ViewMode_PreferenceData>
<ViewMode_PreferenceData>
<iViewID>1</iViewID>
<iDataID>6</iDataID>
<strValue>True</strValue>
</ViewMode_PreferenceData> 
<ViewMode_PreferenceData>
<iViewID>1</iViewID>
<iDataID>4</iDataID>
<strValue>False</strValue>
```

I want to be able to identify any iUserID in which the StrValue for iDataID's 5 and 6 are not set to True.

I have attempted to use a txtValue Like % statement but even if I copy the contents and query for it verbatim it will not yield a result leading me to believe that the XML data cannot be queried in this manner.

[Screenshot of Select * query for this DB for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITkUf.jpg)

Comment: Stack overflow website changed the contained data example due to the brackets etc.   Please reference the screenshot to understand how the data is stored in the txtValue Column

Comment: The mini-markdown formatting on the page makes it impossible to cut and paste the data and keep it in its native form.   I think I am only able to add a screenshot on the initial post, so I am trying to come up with another alternative here

Comment: Perhaps you could post the example DDL and data at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/about.html).

Comment: @Chris: Take the text representation of your data and indent if by four spaces. Check your favorite editor, it might be provide a function to indent the text (or a selection) (but make sure you use spaces **not** tabs) or maybe some regular expression find and replace, that lets you replace the beginning of each line with four spaces. Then edit your question and post that indented text. It will be shown verbatim, in a nice code box.

Answer (score 1):

You can try XML-method `.exist()` together with an `XPath` with predicates:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/BasePreferencesDataSet.xsd') 
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE CAST(txtValue AS XML).exist('/BasePreferencesDataSet
                                   /ViewMode_PreferenceData[iDataID=5 or iDataID=6]
                                   /strValue[text()!="True"]')=1;
```

The namespace-declaration is needed to address the elements without a namespace prefix.

The `<ViewMode_PreferenceData>` is filtered for the fitting IDs, while the `<strValue>` is filtered for a content `!="True"`. This will return any data row, where there is at least one entry, with an ID of 5 or 6 and a value not equal to "True".

Answer (score 0):

So without sample data (including tags; sorry you're having trouble with that) it's tough to craft the complete query, but what you're looking for is XQuery, specifically the [.exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) method in T-SQL.

Something like

```
SELECT iUserID
FROM tblLocalUserPreferences
WHERE iApplicationID = 30 
AND vcKey='MonitorPreferences'
AND (txtValue.exist('//iDataID[text()="5"]/../strValue[text()="True"]') = 0
      OR txtValue.exist('//iDataID[text()="6"]/../strValue[text()="True"]')=0)
```

This should return all userID's where either iDataID 5 or 6 do NOT contain True.  In other words, if both are true, you won't get that row back.

Comment: Looking for another way to add an image, If I cut and paste the data is skewed as a result of the mini-markdown formatting on the website.   I will try to paste it again in this comment.    <BasePreferencesDataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BasePreferencesDataSet.xsd">    <ViewModesTable>      <iViewID>1</iViewID>    </ViewModesTable>    <ViewMode_PreferenceData>      <iViewID>1</iViewID>      <iDataID>0</iDataID>      <strValue>False</strValue>    </ViewMode_PreferenceData>    <ViewMode_PreferenceData>      <iViewID>1</iViewID>      <iDataID>5</iDataID> </ViewMode_PreferenceData>

Comment: looks like it made it; give me a few.

Comment: so in the sample xml you sent, there is no strValue for iDataID 5.  Would you want to see the iUserID for that condition (in other words, it's not set to True)?

Comment: ..and, what happens if there is no dataID of 6?  Do both conditions have to be missing or not True to show up?  If ID 5 = True and ID 6 = False, what happens?

Comment: the data did not fit in the comment size constraints.  I was just trying to get an actual representation of the data into the comment.  Both fields are always populated and visible with either a true or false within the strValue.

Comment: Looking deeper into the table, This is XML data Stored as nvarchar -1.   I am not sure if that changes the query in regards to using the text.exist

Comment: It matters. :).  You’ll have to do a conversion in the query using the convert function before applying the method. Or else use a string function to search.

Comment: Stuart,The condition 5=True and 6=False can exist, they will Always be populated with either a true or false value.